# Why do we have $\lim \sqrt {2 - \sqrt {2 + \sqrt {2 + \sqrt 2 ...}}} (1/2)^n = \pi $?

Tags: limits, pi, polygons, nested-radicals

Why do we have $\lim \sqrt {2 - \sqrt {2 + \sqrt {2 + \sqrt 2 ...}}} (1/2)^n = \pi $ ?

Here $...$ means repeating $n$ times.

I assume it comes from repeated half-angle formulas.

Is this the case ? And if so, is there another way to prove the identity too  ???

Comment: The real question is , why havent I seen this before :) I have only seen the similar vieta product ... Probably easily shown equivalent ...

Comment: Sorry , i did not know it was duplicate.  What happens to duplicates ? Do they get removed ? Can i still see them ? ( I have no exp with this )